# Can not add a group to a auth user

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I want create a user with custom group in `django admin`.
so I write below code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as AuthUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

# these groups have already been created.    
class TestGroup(object):
    Admin = 'Admin'
    Merchant = 'Merchant'
    User = 'User'

class Merchant(AuthUser):

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        super(Merchant, self).save(**kwargs)

        for group in Group.objects.all():
        print group.name

        # way 1
        if not self.groups.filter(name=TestGroup.Merchant).exists():
            print self.groups.filter(name='Merchant').exists()
            g = Group.objects.get(name=TestGroup.Merchant)
            g.user_set.add(self)
            print self.groups.filter(name='Merchant').exists()

        # way 2
        if not self.groups.filter(name=TestGroup.Merchant).exists():
            g = Group.objects.get(name=TestGroup.Merchant)
            self.groups.add(g)


        # way 3
        if not self.groups.filter(name=TestGroup.Merchant).exists():
            g = Group.objects.get(name=TestGroup.Merchant)
            self.groups.add(g)
            self.save()
```

I have tried three ways to add a group to a user.But none of them could work.

**UPDATE:**

You can test by following this steps:

1. create a group named 'Merchant' at django admin
2. add my code (add print in way 1 to test), `syncdb` and so on.
3. create a `Merchant` at django admin.
   you can see log:

   `u'Merchant'`
   `False`
   `True`
4. enter the merchant you just created, you can see, the group merchant is not  selected(means this user do not beyond to this group).
5. click save again,
   you would still see

   `u'Merchant'`
   `False`
   `True`

add group to  merchant fail, very strange.

Comment: Is it perhaps getting confused with django's own Group model, with which the User model already shares a relationship?

Comment: @cms_mgr I remove company name `XXX` from my custom `XXXGroup` before I post this question.I have updated my question.

Comment: If the code posted is accurate now then your `TestGroup` model has no foreign key relationships. You've created three variables: `Admin`, `Merchant` and `User` and assigned strings with the same names to those variables.

Comment: @cms_mgr  TestGroup is just used to define the groups name.Groups with these name have been already created at project startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debug into save method and find:

ValueError: `"<Merchant: m23533>" needs to have a value for field "user" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

It is saying this user have not saved to db yet, that's why adding groups fails!

**solution**:

```
class Merchant(AuthUser):

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        super(Merchant, self).save(force_insert=True) 

        if not self.groups.filter(name=TestGroup.Merchant).exists():
            g = Group.objects.get(name=TestGroup.Merchant)
            g.user_set.add(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your clarifications. From what I can see your problem is the way you're trying to filter and get the Group. You're checking whether the name equals an object instance: `TestGroup.Merchant` when it expects a string. Try:

```
if not self.groups.filter(name='Merchant'):
    g = Group.objects.get(name='Merchant')
    g.user_set.add(self)
```

I've also removed the `exists` part of your if statement because an empty queryset will evaluate to Boolean `False` anyway so `exists` is redundant.

EDIT: Following your comment I'm back to the comment I put on your question. You are assigning strings to variables, not creating groups. If the groups are already created the TestGroup class is completely redundant and should be removed.

At your command prompt import django's Group class and try various things until you can select your groups. Change your code to reflect whatever worked at the command line. For example:

```
for group in Group.objects.all():
    print group.name
```

Then change your code to look up `Group.objects.get(name='relevant_name')`.

Comment: `self.groups.filter(name='Merchant')` equal to `self.groups.filter(name=TestGroup.Merchant)`. You can have a try, the result is same.

Comment: you can follow my steps in question.

Comment: It is absolutely not the same. One returns the object, the other returns a string. They may look the same depending on your model's unicode method but they will not pass an equality test. Try entering `type(TestGroup.Merchant)` at the command line to see what I mean.

Comment: I have use either `TestGroup.Merchant` or `'Merchant'` in my steps, same result.`>>> type(TestGroup.Merchant)
<type 'str'>
>>> type('Merchant')
<type 'str'>`.At least, They are same while you using them as argument

Comment: Absolutely I am not creating groups, because I have already created them.I am always assigning strings or anther type variables into `django filter`, I don't see there is something irrational.

Comment: group do not have `codename`, only `name`. I update that test in my question. 'Merchant' is indeed exist in `django's Group`. You can  follow my steps, Then you would know.